# POST response varies between 200, 500, and 404 unpredictably

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, http-status-code-404, scrapy

Trying to do some scraping of a site that returns a large number of search result. The problem is that the only way to navigate pages is via a __doPostBack method attached to the href argument of each link.

This is my current code:

```
class guruSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "guru"
    allowed_domains = ["guru.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        baseUrl = "http://www.guru.com/emp/search.aspx?keyword=#&&sort=Earnings&page="
        endUrl = "&sort=Earnings"
        target = 'ctl00$empcnt$ucResults$pagination'
        hiddenValue = ";;AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.60919.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e:en-US:311bfa99-1d92-41d7-aace-73bb01d14bf6:475a4ef5:effe2a26:1d3ed089:5546a2b:497ef277:a43b07eb:d2e10b12:37e2e5c9:751cdd15:dfad98a5:3cf12cf1"
        requests = []
        for i in range(1, 5):
            url = baseUrl + str(i)
            argument = str(i+1)
            data = {'__EVENTTARGET': target, '__EVENTARGUMENT': argument,
                    '__ASYNCPOST': 'true', 'ctl00_scriptMgr_HiddenField':hiddenValue}
            currentPage = FormRequest(url, formdata=data)
            requests.append(currentPage)
        return requests
```

This has a sample response of the following:

```
Crawled (404) <POST http://www.guru.com/emp/search.aspx?keyword=#&&sort=Earnings&page=3> (referer: None)
Crawled (200) <POST http://www.guru.com/emp/search.aspx?keyword=#&&sort=Earnings&page=4> (referer: None)
```

Though, on the 200 message the actual return is as follows:

```
<HtmlXPathSelector xpath=None data=u'<html><body><p>179|error|500|The page is'>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm really at my wits end with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that interacting with anything javascript with scrapy is generally a losing battle. Ended up using casperjs to actually do these requests and that worked great. I've heard Selenium also works for things like this, but I haven't actually tried Selenium out.

Just thought I'd give an update.